# Looking for a ":" with queryselector returns a error

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Every time I look for a `:` it returns a error in my console

Here is some of the code

```
div id="Meating1 S8:30 tot E10:00 "
div id="Meating2 S10:10 tot E10:20 "
div id="Meating3 S10:30 tot E11:00 "
ect...
```

I want to highlight the one that is currently active, so I do

```
Lookfordiv="[id*=E"+Our+":"+Min+"]"; 
returndiv=Day.querySelector(Lookfordiv).id;
```

(if it returns "null" it will do time++;)

full error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '[id*=E10:47]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: `[id*="E10:47"]`

Comment: a colon is a special character in a CSS selector, denoting a pseudo-class. So you'll have to escape it or enclose it in quotes, as mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** colons must be escaped with a double backslash

```
Lookfordiv="[id*=E"+Our+"\\:"+Min+"]";
```